# Adding button that will replace the scroll in listView

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

i want to write some control that will contain 2 button and listView. 
Pressing button 1 will scroll the listview up. 
Pressing button 2 will scroll the listview down.

The direct scroll of the listview will be unavailable - ( will be invisible ? ).

1. I  don't find the listview method 'scroll-up'  / 'scroll-down' that i could callon the button event.
2. How can i make the listview scroll to be always visible ?

Someone can help me here ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here, one is easier than the other.

First option (the easier, but slightly hacky way): Using the VisualTreeHelper, get a reference to the ScrollViewer in the ListView's ControlTemplate. Then you can use the LineUp and LineDown methods to scroll the content up and down and the static SetVerticalScrollBarVisibility method to hide the scrollbar. I personally wouldn't use this approach because I don't like relying on the Visual Tree which can change.

Second option (a bit harder, but not too bad if you know how): Write a new Control Template for the ListView (might need to alter the templates for it's ScrollViewer + ScrollBar), adding in two buttons that call the ScrollBar.LineUpCommand and ScrollBar.LineDownCommand. If you want to do this, I'd suggest getting a copy of ShowMeTheTemplate, then you can just copy and paste the original(s) and modify.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.